# Spring Security: Allow requests from specific host name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

While specific IP addresses can be allowed for a given antMatcher using

**Security Config**

```
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasIpAddress("127.0.0.1")
         .anyRequest().permitAll()
        }
}
```

I am unable to find a way to whitelist hostnames eg: "localhost". Is there any way in which a given domain name can be permitted instead of an IP address?

Comment: The request doesn't have a hostname only a remote ip address. So if you want to resolve by hostname it would first need to convert to ip-address (range) and compare. Doing the conversion can be quite a slow operation. But if you really want, you would need to build your own matcher for that.

Comment: Is there any other way to move forward, the actual problem im trying to solve is that i want my application to only accept requests from its reverse proxy gateway and not when accessed directly. Hence im trying to whitelist the gateway hostname while blocking everything else.

Comment: But as mentioned, there is no way to do that (based on hostname) as the original IP address will still be there and not a hostname. Your reverse proxy also has an IP address, which, if setup right should be in one of the `X-Forwarded` headers (or the likes) so you can write a matcher for that.

Comment: Hardcoded IP addresses are a bad pattern in modern networking. Ideally you'd have a zero-trust setup where the network configuration only permits routing to your app from the gateway but assuming you can't do that you could authenticate your gateway using an SSL client cert or a shared secret like an API key in a header known only to the gateway and the backend.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure the security config as follow:

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
        firewall.setAllowedHostnames(hostName -> hostName.equals("myHost.com"));
        web.httpFirewall(firewall);
    }
```